# Expectation of brownian motion at hitting time

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expectation, stopping-times

Am i correct in my derivation? I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}B_{\tau_a}$. From the definition of the hitting time i get $B_{\tau_a}=a$, so $$\mathbb{E}B_{\tau_a}=\mathbb{E}a=a$$ I am new to the subject and it seems too simple to be true...

Comment: The interesting question is why you want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[B_{\tau_a}]$ rather than $\mathbb{E}[{\tau_a}]$

Comment: If it will help you, assume that that I wanted to check myself, if I understand the hitting times in a correct way.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[B_{\tau_a}]$ is the expected position of $B_t$ at the time it hits $a$. That's obviously $a$, by definition. To reiterate Henry, are you sure you didn't mean $\mathbb{E}[{\tau_a}]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - given that the Brownian motion hits $a$, $\mathbb{E}[B_{\tau_a}]=a$.

But note that a Brownian motion with drift away from $a$ will have a positive probability of never hitting $a$.

Even if you have a standard Brownian motion (a Wiener process with no drift, $B_0=0$ and $B_t−B_s$~$ N(0, t−s)$ for $0 \le s \le t$,  $\mathbb{E}[{\tau_a}]=\infty$. If on the other hand $\tau_a$ were the first time the process hits either $a$ or $-a$ (a common use of the notation), then $\mathbb{E}[B_{\tau_a}]=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[{\tau_a}]=a^2$.